# Value categories in languages other than C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I recently have learned about C++11's [value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). Frankly, I was astonished by all the nuances and subtleties. I thought C++ is a very complicated language that I had grasped reasonably well, but every now and then something jumps out and proves me simply naïve.

I'm very curious whether there are other languages that have something similar to value categories. For example, I googled on Java but nothing interesting showed up. And I know C has lvalue/rvalue, but that's basically pre-C++11 C++.

Comment: There are a lot of languages.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Could you give me some examples to look into?

Comment: I use https://www.pearsonhighered.com/product/Sebesta-Concepts-of-Programming-Languages-10th-Edition/9780131395312.html in my teaching. It is a very easy read.

Comment: You'll have to relearn them soon-ish...P0135R1 just passed the committee today.

Comment: @T.C. I know, I know...C++17.

Comment: @T.C Ah that's great news though!

Comment: You mean, is any language as complicated as C++ so that it needs a "value categories" concept just to organize the way to talk about and give requirements related to a myriad semantic attributes that an expression can have? (I can't even think of a language in which there is a form of assignment  A := B  which can destroy B in the process of transferring the value to A, let alone one which tracks the permission to do this as a semantic attribute.)  Destructive-read-out magnetic core memory all over again!

Comment: @t.c found http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html -- where is r1?  Any big differences?

Comment: @Yakk in the post-meeting mailing in a few weeks :) It's the wording paper.

Comment: @Zizheng Tai: Most programming languages don't care about casually making copies of things. In C++... we care. R-value references and such are there to help you write efficient code. I would compare it to Rust, how they have the "borrow checker" which is also quite frustrating to beginners. But if you don't have tools like this, you can't e.g. make a Webserver with "zero copy semantics" afaik. https://github.com/Geal/nom https://github.com/servo/html5ever If you use languages like Java or Ruby, you either have implicit reference counting pointers, or garbage collection, or lots of copies